# INSendMessageIntentHandling sirkit skipping handleSendMessage intent

Tags: ios, objective-c, sirikit

I added NSLog(..) statements on each method but it was not going to the handle send message delegate. I need to get some message from Siri to do some tasks. Also, is there any way to get the date/time from speech with INSentMessageDomiain

## import "IntentHandler.h"

```
// As an example, this class is set up to handle Message intents.
// You will want to replace this or add other intents as appropriate.
// The intents you wish to handle must be declared in the extension's Info.plist.

// You can test your example integration by saying things to Siri like:
// "Send a message using <myApp>"
// "<myApp> John saying hello"
// "Search for messages in <myApp>"

@interface IntentHandler () <INSendMessageIntentHandling, INSearchForMessagesIntentHandling, INSetMessageAttributeIntentHandling>
{
    NSString *resName;
}
@end

@implementation IntentHandler

- (id)handlerForIntent:(INIntent *)intent {
    // This is the default implementation.  If you want different objects to handle different intents,
    // you can override this and return the handler you want for that particular intent.
   
    if ([intent isKindOfClass:[INSendMessageIntent class]]) {
        
    }
    return self;
}
#pragma mark - INSendMessageIntentHandling
// Implement resolution methods to provide additional information about your intent (optional).

- (void)resolveRecipientsForSendMessage:(INSendMessageIntent *)intent withCompletion:(void (^)(NSArray<INPersonResolutionResult *> *resolutionResults))completion {
    // If no recipients were provided we'll need to prompt for a value.
    NSMutableArray<INPersonResolutionResult *> *resolutionResults = [NSMutableArray array];
    
    //NSArray<INPerson *> *recipients = intent.recipients;
    [resolutionResults addObject:[INPersonResolutionResult notRequired]];
    completion(resolutionResults);
}
- (void)resolveContentForSendMessage:(INSendMessageIntent *)intent withCompletion:(void (^)(INStringResolutionResult *resolutionResult))completion {
    NSString *text = intent.content;
    
    if (text.length == 0) {
        completion([INStringResolutionResult needsValue]);
    }
    else {
        completion([INStringResolutionResult successWithResolvedString:text]);
    }
}

// Handle the completed intent (required).
- (void)handleSendMessage:(INSendMessageIntent *)intent completion:(void (^)(INSendMessageIntentResponse *response))completion {
    
     //Implement your application logic to send a message here.
    NSUserActivity *userActivity = [[NSUserActivity alloc] initWithActivityType:NSStringFromClass([INSendMessageIntent class])];
    INSendMessageIntentResponse *response = [[INSendMessageIntentResponse alloc]initWithCode:INSendMessageIntentResponseCodeSuccess userActivity:userActivity];
    completion(response);
}
```